# Passing JavaScript array with multiple values to PHP via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My current project is passing multiple values to php via ajax and I want to add an array together but I failed to do so.

current JS file:

```
var name= 'John';
var age= 21;
var gender = 'm';

var postData = 'name='+name+'&age='+age+'&gender=gender';

$.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      dataType:'json',
      url:baseUrl+'/student',
      data:postData,
    }).done(function (data){
        alert('success');
      }
   });
```

What I want to add:

```
var subject = ["math","geograph"];
JSON.stringify(subject ); //to encode the array
```

I have tried:

```
var postData = 'name='+name+'&age='+age+'&gender='+gender+'&subject='subject';
```

and

```
data:{subject : subject , postData : postData},
```

and I get this array in php:

```
$subject = json_decode($request['subject']),true);
```

But I can't get the array in my php. How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `JSON.stringify(subject)` is still an array

```js
var subject = ["math","geograph"];
console.log(JSON.stringify(subject ));
```

Besides Phil's answer, one option is to using `join()` to do it

```js
var name= 'John';
var age= 21;
var gender = 'm';

var subject = ["math","geograph"];
var subjects = subject.join(",");
var postData = 'name='+name+'&age='+age+'&gender='+gender+'&subjects='+subjects;
console.log(postData);
// in server side,we can using split() to convert subjects to an array
```

Comment: OP would need to use different PHP code in this case... `$subject = explode(',', $_POST['subject'])`

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to url-encode the JSON string to make it compatible with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request you're sending.

Fortunately, jQuery is able to do this for you if you pass it an object of data values.

```js
const name = "John";
const age = 21;
const gender = "m";
const subject = ["math", "geograph"];

$.ajax({
  url: `${baseUrl}/student`,
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    name,
    age,
    gender,
    subject: JSON.stringify(subject),
  }
})
```

This will produce the following request body

```
name=John&age=21&gender=m&subject=%5B%22math%22%2C%22geograph%22%5D
```

On the PHP side you can continue to use...

```php
$subject = json_decode($_POST['subject'], true);
```

---

As indicated in the comments below, you can also skip the JSON encoding in which case jQuery will send multiple fields named `subject[]` so your PHP would have to change to

```php
$subject = $_POST['subject']; // will be an array
```

Comment: Why bother to json encode `subject`? You can just use `data: { name, age, gender, subject }` and `$_POST['subject']` will be an array with values `math` and `geograph`

Comment: If you send data as `data: { name, age, gender, subject }` it will just be `$_POST['subject']`.

Comment: @Nick right you are, sorry. Can you tell I don't use PHP any more 

Comment: Lucky you! :) :)

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is converting the data from object to string by using the `JSON.stringify` like:

```
var name= 'John'; 
var age= 21;
var gender = 'm';
var subject = ["math","geograph"];

var postData = { name: name, age: age, gender: gender, subject: subject};


$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  url:baseUrl+'/student',
  data: JSON.stringify(postData), // or JSON.stringify({name, age, gender, subject }),
  // or
  // data: JSON.stringify({ postData, subject }),
}).done(function (data){
    alert('success');
  }
});
```

then use json_decode in php.

Comment: This will send a JSON string with content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is a mismatch and won't be parseable on the server-side